# Single Click on Check all button issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a check all button on click it will select all the checkboxes. But on my  display page i have 30000 checkboxes which is giving me page unresponsive on click on Check All button. Can somebody please help on this.

```
function js_select_all(btn,theForm){
   if (btn.value == "Check All")  {
       var checkval = "checked";
       if (js_one_row(theForm.circSelected)) {
           theForm.circSelected.checked = checkval;
       } else {
           for (var i=0; i < theForm.circSelected.length; i++){
               theForm.circSelected[i].checked = checkval;
           }
       }
       btn.value ="Uncheck All";
   }else {
       if (js_one_row(theForm.circSelected)) {
           theForm.circSelected.checked = false;
       } else {
           for (var i=0; i < theForm.circSelected.length; i++){
               theForm.circSelected[i].checked = false;
           }
       }
       btn.value = "Check All";
    }
}
```

Can soembody help me to acheive the result in fastest way possible.I am working on a webtoolkit which supports only HTML,CSS and JS.

Comment: Better show demo working snippet.

Comment: You can't really have 30000 records and do some JQuery processing on it. It will definitely hang and make the browser unresponsive. I would rather recommend, whenever select all is clicked, pass that to the server and handle it at the server-end., rather than checking all checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

#### Break the task into smaller chunks, and run them after short delays using setTimeout

This allows the browser to remain responsive. Presumably it is not essential that the tickboxes all change state immediately? The user will presumably be happy that the computer is ticking the boxes, even if it takes a few moments, since otherwise the user would have to do it himself/herself.

Here is an example where we break it into chunks of 100 check boxes, and each chunk done at an interval of 1000 ms.

```
const chunkSize=100;
const intervalBetweenChunksMs = 1000;
for (var i=0; i < theForm.circSelected.length ; i+=chunkSize) { 
  console.log("Creating chunk starting at",i)
  setTimeout(function(start){for(var j=start; j<Math.min(i+chunkSize,33); j++) 
    { 
      console.log("Doing item number", j);
      theForm.circSelected[j].checked = checkval;

    }
  }(i),(1 + theForm.circSelected.length/chunkSize)*intervalBetweenChunksMs ) 
}
```

If this works in principle, you will probably want to try smaller intervals, so that the complete "wave" of checking is done in a reasonable timeframe.

I have put in a "1+" so that the first chunk (starting at item number 0) only occurs after one interval. If this introduces an unacceptable lag before the first visible change, then remove the "1+".